# How to map child entities to same table in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core and I need to map child entities to the same table, because they are of the same type.

Imagine the following scenario of class hierarchy:

```
public class Grandpa
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Father Robert { get; set; }
    public Father Jack { get; set; }
}

public class Father
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    // I use this to reference Grandpa
    public Guid GrandpaId { get; set; }
    public List<Son> MySons { get; set; }
}

public class Son
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    // I use this to reference Father
    public Guid FatherId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now the issue is the following: in my scenario (the above is the abstraction replicating my real scenario), I cannot make `Robert` and `Jack` an array - they need to be there separately. The other thing is, the `Grandpa` entity owns 2 `Father` entities, and each `Father` entity owns a list of `Son` entities.

I want to tell ModelBuilder to generate my tables in such a way that there is ONE TABLE for all `Father` entities, and ONE TABLE for all `Son` entities - because they are all the same entities, and they should never be placed in different tables as their primary keys and foreign keys (IDs) clearly reference who they belong to.

Now, you know, in plain SQL, it's easy to achieve such a structure, very simple to write the SQL code for this. However, how do I do it with EF Core?

I've tried:

1) Specifying all primary keys and foreign keys in model builder, per entity
2) Setup the owned property hierarchy in ModelBuilder using

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Father>()
  .ToTable("Fathers");
modelBuilder.Entity<Son>()
  .ToTable("Sons");
modelBuilder.Entity<Grandpa>(g => 
{
  x.OwnsOne(y => y.Robert, z => 
  { 
    z.OwnsMany(a => a.MySons, b => 
    {
      b.HasKey(k=>k.Id); 
      b.ToTable("Sons"); 
    }); 
    z.ToTable("Fathers"); 
  });
  x.OwnsOne(y => y.Jack, z => 
  { 
    z.OwnsMany(a => a.MySons, b => 
    {
      b.HasKey(k=>k.Id); 
      b.ToTable("Sons"); 
    }); 
    z.ToTable("Fathers"); 
  });
});
```

However, there are errors saying:

```
Cannot use table 'Fathers' for entity type 'Grandpa.Father#Robert' since it is being used for entity type 'Grandpa.Father#Jack' and there is no relationship between their primary keys.
```

I must mention that these entities are part of the same `DbContext` - and they need to remain so, preferably.

The way EF Core maps or fails to map entities is wrong - if I remove the table name specifications, it just creates separate tables for my entities of the same type, which is wrong. I am not even in the case of having the same entity declared in a different namespace/duplicated, but it's actually the same namespace, the same entity, the `Grandpa` entity has two `Father` entities, and each `Father` entity has a `List<Son>`.

Comment: Shouldn't you have a single table called People for all these types? Or is this completely made up?

Comment: It is made up, it's an abstraction of my real scenario - but enough to show the issue at hand. I cannot have a single table called People, as it is not the point here ...

Comment: Had to make sure, it's a pretty questionable abstraction as you have turned relationships into concrete classes. i.e. Father is not an entity. A person is a father to some other person. A Grandpa is not an entity it's a relationship that goes through two people. A Grandpa could be someone else's Father and Son at the same time. Anyway, EF Core does not support mapping owned entities from two different tables to one table even if they are the same CLR type as there is no correlation between the two owners. For that, you have to use a normal relationship instead of ownership.